# How to make a custom split(bottom) menu in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

I am trying to make a split menu (with sherlock or without) and i still did not succeed.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity  {
ActionBarSherlock mSherlock = ActionBarSherlock.wrap(this);
...............
    mSherlock.setUiOptions(ActivityInfo.UIOPTION_SPLIT_ACTION_BAR_WHEN_NARROW);
    mSherlock.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...............
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Used to put dark icons on light action bar
    boolean isLight = false;

    menu.add("You")
        .setTitle("You")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.icon_you : R.drawable.icon_you)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    menu.add("Pet Open")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.icon_pet_open : R.drawable.icon_pet_open)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    menu.add("Around")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.icon_around : R.drawable.icon_around)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return true;
}
```

as a result i get 3 small icons without titles and with a default background, which i don't know how to change. and here is what i want to get:

[image: Split Menu Bottom]

how do i add a custom bottom menu, without affecting the top menu?

here is what i found:

[implement split menu from manifest](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html) (i don't think this would give me the opportunity to change anything i want)

[using layout params](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/He6gst4nvR0) - it looks like it does not work properly.

---

what would be the best way to implement this menu?

---

UPDATE
[here is one more way i found:](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/Overlay/src/com/commonsware/android/inflation)  the good thing is that i can see how to change it, but the bad is that it uses same background on top & bottom, and i am not sure if i can change it.
[image]

Comment: I think the example you added is not much different than your original code. He is using `ActionItem`s as you normally would, he is just setting the `ActionBar` to overlay the screen so that it is sem-transparent. I don't see anything in the code that would more easily let you style your menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options:

1) You can just set the flag in the manifest (or programatically as you do above) to split the `ActionBar`, but this ONLY works if you are on a phone sized device in portrait, and even then it still has the `ActionBar` present up top, but moves the first few `ActionItem`s to the bottom. That would be fine for most situations, but it sounds like you are saying you ALWAYS want this bottom to show and the system menu you would be using would not have the ability to style to the degree you want.

2) Make your own layout for the bottom of the screen to create the styled menu you are talking about. This might work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- this is where the Activity contents go -->
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#8f8"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- this is the green bottom bar -->
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentleft="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- This is the status button -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#00f" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Status"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <!-- This is the Pet Open button -->


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#00f" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Pet Open"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


     <!-- This is the Refresh button -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#00f" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Refresh"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This would work for the 3 buttons, with a bunch of adjustments to make it styled closer to what you want. If you wanted more than 3 to appear on the the bottom, and you wanted to use the provided `MenuItem`'s you could determine all this at runtime in [`onPrepareOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29), and dynamically change a version of the layout above. That would be a lot more work, but might be more what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you. i will give it a try now. please check the updated question, there may be one more way.

Comment: thank you, i think i will go the first way, because at bigger screens the bottom bar would look awful, also on landscape mode the buttons go on top, which is the best deal, as there would be less space, so 3 buttons in landscape mode would get too much height.

Comment: That seems like the best way to go. Generally speaking the `ActionBar` works well, and has just enough built in functionality to make it not worthwhile to make your own custom solution.